# Increasing disk space for VM

Tags: virtual-machine, centos7, esxi

As you can see in the below command I have assigned a total of 500 GB disk space to my VM. But I am seeing 14.4 GB actual space available to the disk and once it gets used completely. I got an error there isn't much space to use? How to extend space for **/dev/mapper/centos-root**.

I am using VMware ESXi and using centOS for this VM.

```
[root@localhost Apr]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 536.9 GB, 536870912000 bytes, 1048576000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00064efd

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    33554431    15727616   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 14.4 GB, 14382268416 bytes, 28090368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 1719 MB, 1719664640 bytes, 3358720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 byte
```

Answer (score 0):

**Execute bellow Steps to increase your Linux Disk after adding space in VMWare   :**

1. Step 1 - update partition table

> fdisk /dev/sda

```
Press p to print the partition table to identify the number of partitions.
Press n to create a new primary partition.
Press p for primary.
Press 3 for the partition number, depending on the output of the partition table print.
Press Enter two times.
Press t to change the system's partition ID.
Press 3 to select the newly creation partition.
Type 8e to change the Hex Code of the partition for Linux LVM.
Press w to write the changes to the partition table.
```

2. Step 2 -  Restart the virtual machine.
3. Step 3 -  verify that the changes were saved

> fdisk -l

4. Step 4 -  convert the new partition to a physical volume

> ```
> pvcreate /dev/sda3
> ```

5. Step 5 -  extend the physical volume (centos is your VG name,  if not use your VG name in place of centos  )

> vgextend centos /dev/sda3

6. Step 6 - extend the Logical Volume  (500G is the size you want to add , if not use the right size in place of 500G)

> lvextend -L+500G /dev/mapper/centos-root

7. Step 7 -  expand the ext filesystem online

> resize2fs /dev/mapper/centos-root

Answer (score 0):

extend disk without reboot

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/rescan
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdb/device/rescan
echo 1 > /sys/block/nvme0n1/device/rescan_controller

partprobe

gdisk fix warnging

parted change partion size

## parted can executed as command line. but this is very dangerous
parted -s /dev/sdb "resizepart 2 -1" quit
parted -s /dev/sdb "resizepart 3 100%" quit
resizepart 3 100%

pvresize /dev/sda3

lvextend -l +100%FREE cs/root

xfs_growfs /dev/cs/root
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off your VMWare WorkStation.
2. Expand via VM ->Settings ->Hardware ->HardDisk(SCSI) -> Expand
3. Install **gparted** and open it. (It has a graphical environment)
4. Choose your "sda" and resize the partition.
5. Perform all operations.